# Props that is being passed into React Route is undefined for the first render when using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently using this rendering method

```
<Route exact path='/bulletinboard' render={(props) => <BulletinBoard {...props} loginList={loginList} />} />
```

to pass the `loginList` state into the component `BulletinBoard` so that I can determine if the user is an admin, then let the page load, if not then redirect to the home page.

However, when I tried to retrieve the prop in the component, I think it shows empty on the first render, hence the `alert` in my `filter` function pops out first time as **You do not have permission**, then after pressing OK, second time as **You have access, as the prop has been retrieved.**.

Below is my codesandbox for easier code reference:

[image: Edit epic-feather-l72oh]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need an `async` function here, getting a prop from `props` is not something that needs to be awaited, it's not a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you're simply addressing an attribute of an object.

Second, your usage of `filter` is incorrect. The purpose of `filter` is to return a new array of items that only match the predicate you provide, which is definitely not what you want to do here.

I have a hunch you want to use `some`, which returns whether any element in the array matches the predicate. Here is what I did and it worked for me, let me know if this is what you intended

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const BulletinBoard = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const loginListFromParent = props.loginList;
    console.log(loginListFromParent);
    const isAdmin = loginListFromParent.some( item => item.permissionName.includes("Admin"))
    const message = isAdmin ? 'You have access to this page' : 'You have no permissions to access this page';
    alert(message);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Bulletin Board</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BulletinBoard;
```

Comment: You're right, ```some``` is actually what I should've used, thanks a lot. One more question though, I know this method works in the sandbox, but when I tried it in my real code, it works when I navigate to ```Bulletin Board``` from the home page, but if I refresh or go to the page directly by entering the url, it will have the same problem as before.

Comment: I've updated my sandbox to show how I get the ```loginList``` at the ```App.js```, but I'm not sure how I can replicate the same thing without posting my API link. Basically I get the ```Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser``` from AWS Cognito and pass the attribute from it to the ```axios.get``` and then set the ```loginList``` state from there, then only passing the ```loginList``` that I get from the axios request into ```BulletinBoard```.

Comment: This probably happens because your app is rendered before the `loginList` is ready. Try adding a loading state to your app, and only change it when the list is fetched and ready. If the app is not ready, display a loader element of some sort instead of the `BrowserRotuer`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, adding a loading state is exactly what I needed!